# How to stop attachment(using TRIX) being uploaded to server until submit button is not pressed? Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a form with some input fields. Everything works fine but when I'm attaching file(**TRIX Editor to upload Image or PDF**) with attachment button then it is being directly uploaded to server(LOCALHOST) before submitting the form. Other field(WORKs fine) values or inputs are being only uploaded to server after submit button pressed except attachment.

I want to upload the file only after pressing the submit button.

Here is FORM in open_file.blade.php:

```
    <form method="GET" action="{{route('visitor.update', [auth()->user()->id])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

     @csrf
                                        
    <div class="form-group row"> 
    <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right" for="heading_1">Headline</label>
    <div class="col-md-6"> 
    
    <input type="text" name="heading_1" class="form-control @error('question') border-red @enderror" placeholder="Topic Name" >
    
    </div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="file" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Image Upload</label>
    <div class="col-md-6"> 
                                            
    <input required type="hidden" class="form-control" id="file" name="file">
    <trix-editor name="file" input="file"></trix-editor>                                   
    
    </div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="summary_1" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Description</label>
    <div class="col-md-6"> 
                                                 
    <textarea name="summary_1" rows="5" cols="40" class="form-control tinymce-editor"></textarea>
        
    </div> 
    </div>
        
    <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right" for="frame_1">Embed Link</label>
    <div class="col-md-6"> 
    
     <input type="url" name="frame_1" class="form-control" placeholder="Paste URL here to Embed">
    
     </div>    
     </div>
        
    <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right" for="url_1">Download Link</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    
    <input type="url" name="url_1" class="form-control placeholder="Paste URL here" >
    
    </div>                                       
    </div>
        
    <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right" for="date_1">Upload Date</label>
    <div class="col-md-6"> 
    
    <input name="date_1" id="date" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Upload" value="{{$current_date}}"/>
                                        
    </div>
    </div>                      
        
    <div class="form-group text-center mt-4">
    
    <button type="submit" id="submit" style="width: 100%" class="btn btn-danger" value="Save">Post</button>
        
    </div>                           
        
    </form>
```

Here is **upload** function from Controller:

```
public function upload(Request $request){   
    
if($request->hasFile('file')) {

        $this->validate($request, [
            "file" => "mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,pdf|required|max:2000",
       ],

    );

        $filenamewithextension = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
 
        $filename = pathinfo($filenamewithextension, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
 
        $extension = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
 
        $filenametostore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
 
        $request->file('file')->storeAs('uploads', $filenametostore);

        $path = asset('storage/uploads/'.$filenametostore);

        DB::table('images')->insert([
            'image'=> $path
        ]);
        
        echo $path;

        exit;

    } 
}
```

updates function from Controller:

```
public function updates(Request $request)
    {   
        $visitor = (new User)->updatesUser($request->all(), auth()->user()->id);
    
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'File upadted!');
    }
```

Routes web.php:

```
Route::get('/open_file', 'VisitorController@open_file')->name('visitor.open_file')->middleware('auth');

Route::resource('updates','VisitorController');

Route::post('upload', 'VisitorController@upload');
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

The problem was in route, I changed Form submission to POST

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('visitor.update', [auth()->user()->id])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">@csrf
                                
@method('GET')
```

and route to GET:

```
Route::get('/open_file', 'VisitorController@open_file')->name('visitor.open_file')->middleware('auth');

Route::get('updates','VisitorController@updates');
```

and also paste the Upload method into Updates method.